# XNA - UV texture or shader texture?

Tags: xna, textures, shader

I'm trying to decide whether to draw a texture on geometry using UV texture mapping or drawing it with a shader. Any benefit to doing it either way? Why would you choose one over the other? This is in XNA 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, shaders use UV texture mapping. So there is no real choice.

UV-mapping states that you define address values that map from your object to your texture. I have the following references for you:

- http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976075%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx